# How to flexible the results in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

How to make my script to be flexible? I mean, if there's a new person added in the table, it would not need to do a modification in the sql script. Please help me. I really need help.

Thank you.

Here's the sql script:

```
select 'Data'
||','||to_char(d.dtime_day,'MM/dd/yyyy')
||','||nvl(d.total,0)
||','||nvl(r.total,0)
||','||nvl(rj.total,0)
||','||nvl(a.total,0)
from table1 d
left join(
      select trunc(t.create_time, 'DD') as ddate
            ,u.name as person1
            ,count(t.responsible_user_id) as total
      from table2 t
      left join table3 u
      on t.responsible_user_id=u.id
      where u.id in (3,35)
      and u.title like '%name'
      group by trunc(t.create_time, 'DD')
              ,u.name
 ) d on d.dtime_day = d.ddate
 left join(
      select trunc(t.create_time, 'DD') as ddate
            ,u.name as person2
            ,count(t.responsible_user_id) as total
      from table2 t
      left join table3 u
      on t.responsible_user_id=u.id
      where u.id in (4,39)
      and u.title like '%name'
      group by trunc(t.create_time, 'DD')
              ,u.name
  ) r on d.dtime_day = r.ddate
  left join(
      select trunc(t.create_time, 'DD') as ddate
            ,u.name as person3
            ,count(t.responsible_user_id) as total
      from table2 t
      left join table3 u
      on t.responsible_user_id=u.id
      where u.id in (8,59)
      and u.title like '%name'
      group by trunc(t.create_time, 'DD')
              ,u.name
 ) rj on d.dtime_day = rj.ddate
 left join(
      select trunc(t.create_time, 'DD') as ddate
            ,u.name as person4
            ,count(t.responsible_user_id) as total
      from table2 t
      left join table3 u
      on t.responsible_user_id=u.id
      where u.id in (25)
      and u.title like '%name'
      group by trunc(t.create_time, 'DD')
              ,u.name
  ) a on d.dtime_day = a.ddate
  where d.dtime_day between trunc(sysdate,'DD')-12*7 and trunc(sysdate) -1
 and trunc(d.dtime_day, 'DD')= d.dtime_day
 order by d.dtime_day;
```

Comment: I believe youa re using the output of this select query in an insert statement. Assuming that , What part of this query you need to modify at present ?

Comment: @Asfakul Islam all data inside of left join. I want it to be dynamically, so that if ever there's a new person, it will query automatically

Comment: Okay ..Which part of the inner left joins needs to be dynamic? All the tables ? or something else?

Comment: @Asfakul Islam all the tables that contains left join

Comment: So the table names would change for every new users.?   Based on what conditions?

Comment: @AsfakulIslam no, every responsible id would change for every users, the table name still remain. possible to use pivot?

Comment: Is there only one responsible_id against a user_id?

Comment: This query likely isn't getting the results you expect, as you have `GROUP BY` columns that you aren't reporting (so you have no idea what the results actually mean).  Given your outer date/time range query, you likely want to do some sort of summation there as well... We need sample source data and desired results.  How do you know which users to group together?  Why are you concatenating the final results?

Answer (score -1):

I didn't try this but I think you can create a view from the SQL script, after that you can create a trigger which triggers before insert key and replaces the view.
 it's just an idea.

Comment: What?  This doesn't appear to be related... could you explain more about how it would solve the problem?